# Limit array size

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array with data elements, in this example numbers, like this:

```
var a = [432, 238, 122, 883, 983];
```

And I want to limit the array, so that everytime I add an element to the array, it always keeps a length of let's say 7, or less and removes the oldest elements.

My current aproach looks like this:

```
function add(x) {
    a.unshift(x);
    a = a.slice(0, 7);
}
```

It works just fine, but isn't there a more elegant way to do it, like one line or something?

Edit:
By "more elegant" I mean so that I don't need the add function and just easily could inline the code where I need it, without typing out a for example three times, and only having one line would also make the code "clearer"

Comment: "one line" doesn't means "more elegant way". Your code is good as this.

Comment: Why? This code is short, readable, does what you want, anyone can understand it. Why would you hunt for shorter variant of something that's already so short?

Comment: `a = [x, ...a.slice(0, 6)]`

Comment: Just a pointer, if your code works fine and objective of this question is to improve/optimize, [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place.

Comment: The whole point of the function is to handle adding the new data and then ensuring a maximum length, which is what it does.  Your code will only ever call `add(n);` so it's already minimised in a very sensible manner.  There is no benefit to taking this any further.

Comment: You can simply remove the oldest item if the length passed the count you want. have a look at my answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just to add another possible alternative:

```
a = [x, ...a.slice(0, 6)];
```

Even though I would personally choose [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242954/251311) (with a "better" condition for changing length and for older environments where ES6 is not supported)

References:

- [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: What is the browser support for this?

Answer (score 10):

Just adjust the length property after pushing.

```
function add(x) {
    a.unshift(x);
    a.length = a.length < 7 ? a.length : 7;
}
```

The cleanes way is to check before

```
function add(x) {
    a.unshift(x);
    if (a.length > 7) {
        a.length = 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: You still need to check if the current length is larger than 7, otherwise it will expand smaller arrays with holes.

Comment: `a.length = a.length < 7 ? a.length : 7;` --- ugh, that's nasty :-)

Comment: You can try a.length = Math.min(a.length,7)

Comment: Or `if (a.length > 7) a.length = 7;`, there is nothing bad in imperative code.

Comment: @zerkms or `(a.length > 7) && (a.length = 7)`

Comment: @Murplyx that's nasty as well.

Comment: @zerkms why dont u post a = [x, ...a.slice(0, 6)]

Comment: @Murplyx I just have :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the length of array when adding and Shift it (remove the first element) if the length has passed:

```
function add(x) {
    a.push(x);
    if (a.length > 7)
        a.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can modify the prototype of the `Array` object. This way all of your arrays can have their own max length.

This is cheap and effective, but it may not work well with other libraries and plugins.

```js
Array.prototype.maxLength = Number.MAX_VALUE;
Array.prototype.add = function(item) {
  this.push(item);
  this.adjustLength();
}
Array.prototype.adjustLength = function() {
  this.length = Math.min(this.length, this.maxLength);
}


var a = [432, 238, 122, 883, 983];
a.maxLength = 7;

a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3); // Ignored
a.add(4); // Ignored

document.body.innerHTML = '<ol start="0">'+a.map(function(i){return'<li>'+i+'</li>'}).join('')+'</ol>';
```

```css
ol li:before { content: '\0020\21d2\0020'; }
```

If you create your own class object and delegate to an underlying array, you can make this more portable and extensible.

```js
function MyList(arr, maxLength) {
  this.arr = arr || [];
  this.maxLength = maxLength || Number.MAX_VALUE;
}

MyList.prototype = {
  add : function(item) {
    this.arr.push(item);
    this.adjustLength();
  },
  adjustLength : function() {
    this.arr.length = Math.min(this.arr.length, this.maxLength);
  },
  get : function() {
    return this.arr;
  }
};

var a = new MyList([432, 238, 122, 883, 983], 7);

a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3); // Ignored
a.add(4); // Ignored

document.body.innerHTML = '<ol start="0">'+a.get().map(function(i){return'<li>'+i+'</li>'}).join('')+'</ol>';
```

```css
ol li:before { content: '\0020\21d2\0020'; }
```

---

## Update

Here is a solution that allows you to add many items at once. It silently ignores any overflow. You could throw an error if the maximum length is ever exceeded.

```js
// Recursive sub-routine
function pushAll(source, items, maxLength) {
  if (source.length === maxLength || items.length === 0) return; 
  const [removed] = items.splice(0, 1);
  source.push(removed);
  pushAll(source, items, maxLength);
}

Array.prototype.maxLength = Number.MAX_VALUE;
Array.prototype.add = function(...items) {
  pushAll(this, items, this.maxLength);
};

const a = [432, 238, 122, 883, 983];
a.maxLength = 8;

a.add(1, 2); // Add 1 and 2
a.add(3, 4); // Add only 3
a.add(5);    // Ignored...

document.body.innerHTML = `
  <ol start="0">
    ${a.map((item) =>
       `<li>${item}</li>`
    ).join('')}
  </ol>
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=add(188);

function add(x){
  a.push(x);
  return a.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some context to your answer, explaining how it answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Array.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop). Also if you wish to add a property to array, you can make it generic.

```js
Array.prototype.Limit_push = function(x) {
  this.unshift(x);
  if (this.maxLength !== undefined && this.length > this.maxLength) 
    this.pop();
}

var a = [];
a.maxLength = 7
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  a.Limit_push(i);
  console.log(a)
}

var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  b.Limit_push(i);
  console.log(b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "curried" version of Nina Scholz's solution above (in typescript):

```
export const fixedArrayPush = <T>(size: number, arr: T[]) => (x: T) => {
    arr.unshift(x);
    if (arr.length > size) {
        arr.length = size;
    }
}
```

```
const myData : Data[] = [];
const addData = fixedArrayPush(7, myData);

addData({time: 123, temp: 100});
```